# How to use Thymeleaf ID in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have been using HTML to assign my ID in Thymeleaf (data is from PostgreSQL, framework SpringBoot on Eclipse. PHP and JQuery not included in syllabus).

I want to check if the user has not selected any radio buttons, and want to try it on Javascript.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<!-- CSSの読み込み -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/examMain.css">
<title>模擬試験オンラインー英単語試験</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="/result" data-th-object="${form}">
        <!-- ヘッダータイトル -->
        <div class="headerbackground">
            <h6>模擬試験オンライン</h6>
        </div>
        <br>
        <!-- 試験指示 -->
        <div class="examinstruction">
            <p>表示された言葉の英単語を以下から1つを選び、</p>
            <p>OKボタンをクリックしてください。</p>
        </div>
        <br>
        <!-- 質問 -->

        <div data-th-each="list, st : ${form.list}">
            <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px;">
                <span data-th-text="${list.questionCount}">n</span> <span>/</span> <span
                    data-th-text="${list.questionTotal}">/n</span>
            </p>
            <div class="questionborder">
                <p style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: bold"
                    data-th-text="${list.content}">question</p>
            </div>
            <!-- 解答選択肢 -->
            <fieldset style="border: 0">
                <div class="choiceradiobox"
                    data-th-each="choice, stat : ${list.choice}">
                    <input data-th-id="|choice_id${st.index}${stat.index}|"
                        data-th-name="|choice${st.count}|" type="radio"
                        data-th-value="${choice}"
                        data-th-field="*{list[__${st.index}__].choiceAnswer}" /> <br>
                    <label data-th-for="|choice_id${st.index}${stat.index}|"
                        data-th-text="${choice}"></label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <!-- 解答完了ボタン -->
        <div class="submitsection">
            <input class="btn btn-secondary" style="font-size: 25px"
                type="submit" value="OK!">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Have been stuck on the Id part- Is there any way to change this bit

```
data-th-id="|choice_id${st.index}${stat.index}|"
```

to Javascript code as something that starts with document.getElementById like this?

```
var choiceselect = document.getElementById("|choice_id${st.index}${stat.index}|".checked);
```

I read the official Thymeleaf document but still could not understand the Js part :( (the code above creates an error that says java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i figured it out- for radio buttons instead of the id it's best to use the name.
like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    var radio_choice = document.getElementsByName("list[" + j +"].choiceAnswer");
```